# best solution for a SOAP to Rest gateway

Tags: rest, web-services, api, soap, api-gateway

I have a SOAP API I need converted to Rest. I need help finding solutions to manage translations from SOAP to Rest.

I have implemented a new set of Restful APIs, taking what once was a single SOAP request that manipulated mutiple objects into individual Rest calls that focus on a single object.

For example:

In a single Soap call createUser():
1. Create user profile information
2. Create an account
3. Send a welcome email

This is now broken down into three calls:

1. createProfile()
2. createAccount()
3. notifyUser()

Basic things I am looking for:

1. Allows for a SOAP API to be converted to a Rest API
2. Allows for a single SOAP request to translate to multiple Rest API requests
3. Manages chained Rest API requests (if one SOAP call results in multiple Rest calls, we need to manage things like first call succeeds, but second one fails)
4. Needs to map all error messages
5. Needs to be scaleable

There are commercial solutions (Apigee) and open source solutions (Kong).

My question is:

1. What solutions would work?
2. What solutions should I do a POC with first?

Thanks!

Comment: Apache-camel is very well suited for this.

Comment: I´ve got a problem like that, regarding to an ASP.NET Web Forms app with some ASMX web services. To solve it, I´m working on an ASP .NET Core 2 WebAPI app that works as a kind of "gateway", exposing APIs and internally redirecting to the original ASMX Web Service.  Have you ever tried/considered something like that, making your own gateway?

Answer (score 0):

May be its too late,

But I had a similar problem and after considering all options, I went ahead with manually building it with strongloop loopback framework, it has soap to rest conversion (xml to json and json to xml too) built in and is quite easy to scaffold stuff with

Check it out here : https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-soap